Uncovering criminal activity of a fellow Jew while preparing a civil case
Bs'D. If, while preparing a civil case in the secular courts (because there is no other alternative to respond), it is discovered that the opposing parties have committed very serious financial crimes and fraud, is it permissible to present those crimes to a secular Court for prosecution? Especially since it is very likely that that would quash the civil case.
If not, would it be permitted to continue with the civil case even though it would almost certainly lead to criminal prosecution?
Failure to continue the civil case would result in great loss to individuals and a congregation.
Thanks in advance for all answers.

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Your question might be closed because this site is not a good place for personal questions. Those should be asked to a rabbi well-versed in the relevant laws who will ask questions on context and personal specifics to come to a good answer. This site can't substitute for this. Please don't let this deter you from coming back to learn with us.

I tried to ask this question in a generic form and do not plan to act upon it directly in any way. Mostly I am hoping for some good sources in gmora and tshuvas of poskim. If you could help in any way with regard to this it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

If criminal prosecution would quash the civil case, and pursuing the civil case will inevitably result in criminal prosecution, what's the benefit to the plaintiff?

"Because there is no alternative"  other than hauling another Jew to court for a civil matter -- did you first get a Beit Din to agree to that determination and sign off on it, or jump to that conclusion yourself? Anyhow -- these are really complicated questions that need a posek. If a Beit Din signs off on a heter arkaos -- allowing someone to go to civil courts for a civil matters -- then they should also issue guidance about how to handle criminality.

@shmosel I think James was providing a scenario like the following: Reuven is suing Shimon and Congregation Beis Levi in a secular court. Shimon's lawyer has discovered clear evidence that Reuven is in the wrong and indeed was committing serious crimes. If Shimon and his lawyer present the evidence to the court, this will cause the civil case to be quashed (whether dismissed or perhaps with some other judgment in favor of Shimon and the shul), and additionally Reuven will likely face criminal prosecution.

@Fred if Reuven is suing in secular court without rabbinic approval, we apply the concept of "throw the brick wall at him", no? Proceed with court, even if he wants to switch back to beit din because court's not going well for him. By that logic, I'd imagine that once he's chosen to go to court, then yes we will show up to court and not tie our hands behind our backs vis-a-vis raising criminal conduct either. No?
